# finding and copying files with directory names

Tags: shell, copy, find, command

I have a folder with a lot of subdirectories. I want to find `html.txt` files and move them into a new directory with the same structure.
I´m using

```
find . -name "*.html.txt" | cp -t /home/....
```

but it is not keeping the name and directory structure.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: You could use `find . -name "*.html.txt" | cpio -pdm /home/where/ever`.  You could use `find . -name "*.html.txt" | tar -cf - -T - | tar -xf - -C /home/where/ever` (but it involves two `tar` commands which is clumsier than the single `cpio` command).  There are undoubtedly other options (`rsync`, …).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find . -name '*.html.txt' | xargs cp -t /home --parents
```

`xargs` is often useful to turn various lists into a list of arguments, especially with the output of 'find'. You can probably also do this with an exec command from within find, but I always find that harder to quickly get right.

`--parents` does the trick of creating all the parent directories as they are in the list of files.

I'm using this type of command in csh, and it should work in bash as well.

Mostly answered here already:
https://serverfault.com/questions/180853/how-to-copy-file-preserving-directory-path-in-linux